# PHP : Unidentified Index Error on File Upload

Tags: indexing, upload, file-handling

This is my code. I am getting an unidentified index error for the name of the file i.e 'userfile'. It's a very basic code but I don't get where I am going wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        File Upload
    </title>
</head>
<body>
<h2> Your file contains : <br></h2>
<?php
        $handle = fopen($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], "r");
        while (!feof($handle)) {
            $text = fgets($handle);
            echo $text, "<br/>";
        }
        fclose($handle);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work to print file content

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        File Upload 
    </title>
    <form name="myform" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="userfile"/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</head>
<body>
    <h2> Your file contains : <br> </h2>
            <?php
                    $file = file_get_contents($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);
                    echo $file;
            ?> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Comment: I edited the code, but it did not solve the problem. The new error reads, filename cannot be empty along with showing the unidentified index:userfile error.